# Login con Ajax que no devuelve nada

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

estoy haciendo un login con php, mysql y ajax. He usado la misma estructura para hacer un insertar y un actualizar datos y me trabajo bien. Ahora estoy lo adapte para el login, pero no logro que funcione. Puse un `alert` en varias partes del codigo para ver donde era que dejaba de funcionar. Por lo que pude ver, el problema esta en la funcion `success` de ajax. En la pagina php que es la de control de login, deberia devolver un arreglo convertido en json que incluye un mensaje, error y el rol del usuario. Segun el rol, se debe redirigir a una pagina en especifica. Puse un `console.log` para ver el json devuelto por php, pero no muestra nada. Les dejo el codigo para que puedan revisarlo y gracias de ante mano.
Tengo una duda ¿el `switch` deberia hacerlo en el controlador o hacerlo en el ajax?

Este es el codigo que lanza la funcion de login

```
//------Pág Index------\\
    $("#alerta_login").hide();
    $("#btn_enviar").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        login_AJAX();
    });
```

El ajax

```
//Función para login
function login_AJAX() { 
    //alert ("hasta aquí");
    var datos = $("#form_login").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../controlador/cc-login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
            if (!e.error) {
                console.log(e);
                switch (e.rol) {
                    case 1:
                        location.href = "../vista/pages/postgrados.php";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        location.href = "../vista/pages/reportes.php";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert ("Rol no encontrado");      
                        break;
                }       
                MostrarMensaje($("#alerta_login"));
                $("#form_login").trigger('reset'); 
            } 
        }
    })

}
```

Este es el php de control de login

```
    // Crear arreglo con valores por defecto
    $salida = ['error' => true, 'rol' => 1, 'mensaje' => 'Acción no reconocida'];

    //Auntentificar Usuario
    $result = $ob->Autenticar($usuario, $password);
    
    if(count($result) == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $result[0]['nombre'];
        $salida['error'] = false;
        
        //Gestion de roles
        $_SESSION['rol'], $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];
    } else {
        if (trim($usuario) == "" || trim($password) == "") {
            $salida['mensaje'] = 'Excisten campos vacios'; 
        }else{
            $salida['mensaje'] = 'Datos Incorrectos'; 
        } 
    }
            
    // Devolver resultado en formato JSON
    echo json_encode($salida);
```

Comment: amigo el pedido ajax si debe estar devolviendo algo. En tu configuracion de $.ajax especificas que recibes un json, en el caso en el que el servidor no cumpla esto en algun lugar deberia mostrar un error. posiblemente en la consola del navegador, donde igualmente se deberia mostrar la solicitud con tu datos de envio y la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: te propongo analizar el caso en la consola del navegador. si en el servidor no se cumple: if(count($result) == 1) la variable $salida['error'] nunca toma el valor false y por tanto no ejecuta codigo en tu metodo success debido a que no se cumple if (!e.error)

Comment: Tienes un error, en vez de coma `$_SESSION['rol'], $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];`, debería haber un signo igual: `$_SESSION['rol'] = $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];` para que ambas variables tengan el mismo valor.

Comment: Entonces que debería hacer?? Quité el ```if(!e.error)``` para que mostrara si o si el valor en consola y aún así no mostró nada. Arreglé lo de la coma, pensé k PHP aceptaría eso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es saber qué es lo que está pasando con la petición:

- Dentro de `success`:

  - Analizar si hubo error al procesar los datos en PHP, de ser el caso, enviarlo a la consola
  - Si no hay error (`else`), verificar rol y procesar
- Agregar captura de `error` en la petición

  - Permite saber si algo falló en la conexión entre Javascript y PHP
  - Pudo ser error de red, como URL incorrecta (generalmente error 404)
  - Es probable que haya un error de sintaxis en PHP (generalmente error 500)
  - No se pudo convertir la respuesta en JSON

Si la petición se ejecutó correctamente, dentro de `success` controlas los posibles errores de nombre de usuario/contraseña incorrectos, rol incorrecto, etc. Cualquier otro error aparecerá en la consola y te dará una pista para corregirlo.

```
//Función para login
function login_AJAX() { 
    //alert ("hasta aquí");
    var datos = $("#form_login").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../controlador/cc-login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.error) {
                // Hubo error, mostrar mensaje en consola
                console.log(data.message);
            } else {
                // No hubo error
                // Ver qué se recibió en consola
                console.log(data);
                switch (data.rol) {
                    case 1:
                        location.href = "../vista/pages/postgrados.php";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        location.href = "../vista/pages/reportes.php";
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert ("Rol no encontrado");      
                        break;
                }       
            }
            // Fuera del if, para mostrar mensaje de error
            // cuando no se haya hecho la redirección
            MostrarMensaje($("#alerta_login"));
           $("#form_login").trigger('reset'); 
        },
        // Agregar captura de error en petición AJAX
        error: function(e) {
            // Ver contenido del error en consola
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

En PHP también hay que analizar cualquier posibilidad de error:

- Que los datos hayan sido proporcionados; no importa si lo verificaste en Javascript, siempre se debe validar en el servidor
- Que los datos no estén vacíos; no debes ejecutar la consulta si usuario o contraseña están vacíos
- Después de ejecutar la consulta, verificar si hay resultados

```
// Crear arreglo con valores por defecto
$salida = ['error' => true, 'rol' => 1, 'mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos'];

// Obtener usuario y contraseña desde $_POST, con asignación ternaria
// Recuerda usar los mismos nombres que tienes en el formulario
$usuario = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? trim($_POST['usuario']) : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? trim($_POST['password']) : '';

// Lo primero es revisar que los datos no estén vacíos
if(empty($usuario) || empty($password)) {
    $salida['mensaje'] = 'Nombre de usuario y contraseña no deben estar vacíos.';
} else {
    //Auntentificar Usuario
    $result = $ob->Autenticar($usuario, $password);
    if(count($result) == 1){
    // Asignar variables de sesión necesarias
        $_SESSION['username'] = $result[0]['nombre'];
        //Gestion de roles, ambas variables con signo =, no con coma
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];
        $salida['error'] = false;
    } else {
        // No es necesario, ya está considerado este error
        // porque se definió la variable $salida
        // considerando que usuario y contraseña son inválidos
    }
}
// Devolver resultado en formato JSON
echo json_encode($salida);
```

En cuanto al error que tenías en PHP, al separar por coma, seguramente te generaba un error 500 por `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ...` y, como no tenías captura de error en la petición AJAX, no se mostraba nada en la consola

```
$_SESSION['rol'], $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];
```

Debes asignar primero una variable y después la otra:

```
$salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];
$_SESSION['rol'] = $salida['rol'];
```

Aunque se puede hacer en una sola línea y es exactamente lo mismo que el código anterior:

```
$_SESSION['rol'] = $salida['rol'] = $result[0]['idRol'];
```